# calling a object directly in dojo structure

Tags: dojo

I have a js file that is simply just using the dojo provide statement to give the namespace for an object.
Its a simple settings file that will be referenced for settings throughout the application. 
So Instead of creating a class (module) specifically for these properties I thought I would just give it a name space and reference that in my app js file.

Here is what I have

```
dojo.provide('app');

dojo.require('settings');

dojo.ready(function(){
    console.log("settings = ", settings.obj.prop1);

});
```

**Then in my settings.js**

```
dojo.provide('settings');

var obj = {
    prop1:'property 1',
    prop2:'http://fdsfsdfs'
}


console.log("settings module loaded");
```

When I use required in my app.js it shows me the settings.js has loaded as the console trace shows me its loaded.
But when I try to do a trace on the obj that is inside of settings its saying undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a *global* variable obj. You should define inside settings, where you want it

```
settings.obj = { ... };
```

instead of

```
var obj = { ... }
```

Comment: To attempt to clarify this a bit, it's important to note that dojo doesn't magically namespace everything defined within a module under the module's namespace.  You're generally expected to uphold the namespace yourself.  So while `dojo.provide` ensures that the namespaced object you intend to define within the module exists (e.g. `settings.obj`), you still need to refer to it in full as `settings.obj` within that module (and anywhere else).  Hope that helps.